# How i can make My Server BASEURL dynamic as a frontend developer?

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, react-native, flutter

As a Front-end developer Does making my server URL dynamics before the route name is good?
like https://example.com/api/routeame if I make the "https://example.com/api/ "as a dynamic to come from outside is that good ?!
if it's good how I will implement this faraway firebase dynamic link cause it's made for not that purpose

Comment: You can do that according to your system requirement if you think if you have a same application with will communicate with different servers you can do that

Comment: you can also store your all base urls on primary server and get base url first from there and then make your url it could be helpfull in that case you have  many customers with different servers and and every customer will use same front end application in that case it will be helpfull

Answer (score 0):

I will come to the answer, but before that, one a quick look at the URL, it seems like you are planning to use `/api/routename` as a view URL.

This convention is not good. I would rather do the below-

My `Routes` will be a URL without `/api` and the API's this `Route` component will call will have the `/api` attached to it.

Route Name -> https://example.com/routename (without the `/api`. This is what the browser address bar will show)

API calls -> https://example.com/api/endpoint (internal API call from the `routename` component. This is what you will see in the `network` tab when this component makes the call to the backend API).

And finally, to answer your question, you should only make the host dynamic when you develop the web application.

Because, any other changes needed in the URL (be it changing `/api` to `/xyz` in the calls, removing `/api` from the URL in the network calls, etc) you can always do it from your network layer by adding a `reverse proxy` or with some `redirect` configurations using `nginx` or something similar.

So, make only the `domain` dynamic. For the rest, we should use the network layer tools which is recommended solution.